# Passing struct-like data between C and Haskell via the FFI

Tags: c, haskell, ffi

Consider a Haskell data-type which looks like this

```
data MyData = MyData { arrInt :: [Int] , arrDouble :: [Double], arraySize :: N }
```

Here N represents the sizes of both the arrays the MyData record.

Is it possible to pass this (or some kind of Haskell "pointer" of a MyData object) to a C function which looks like this.

```
int myfunc (int* a, double* b, int N)
```

I am able to use the FFI to call C functions accepting and returning simple datat-types like Double, Int, Char etc. But for more complicated types I don't know what to do.

Comment: Will the C routine modify the two arrays?

Comment: @chi No. At least not for the applications I have in mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like that:

```
import Foreign
import Foreign.C

myfunc :: MyData -> IO CInt
myfunc d =
    withArray (map fromIntegral $ arrInt d) $ \arr1 ->
        withArray (map CDouble $ arrDouble d) $ \arr2 ->
            c_myfunc arr1 arr2 (fromIntegral $ arraySize d)

foreign import ccall safe "myfunc"
    c_myfunc :: Ptr CInt -> Ptr CDouble -> CInt -> IO CInt
```

Comment: Interesting! Is the data inside "d" copied into a separate corresponding C-struct, on which c_myfunc operates? Or does c_myfunc operate directly on the "d" record, as if it were a C-type. This would be very important to know for performance when dealing with large data.

Comment: It is copied to a separate structure. In general, haskell's representation of most complex data types is significantly different than C, so passing data to and from C involves a lot of copying. You can avoid that in the few cases where you have no need to do any processing of the data in one of the two languages. In that case, you just store the data in the format of language that does the processing.

Comment: @smilingbuddha A copy is needed. The Haskell memory layout for `[Int]` is not a contiguous array like in C. Note that if the function modifies those arrays the changes will not be reflected in the pure `MyData` argument, of course. If needed, one can make `myfunc` return a new updated `MyData`.

Comment: @chi Thanks! What if instead of [Int] I had something like the REPA arrays where I believe they are essentially arrays are stored in contiguous memory?

Comment: I was wondering a similar question... I guess there should be a mutable vector data type in some Haskell package which lets you do this without a copy. I have no pointer to contribute, though. You could search hackage for "(mutable) unboxed vector" and see if there's something useful.

Comment: Have a look at `Data.Vector.Storable` and `Data.Vector.Storable.Mutable`.

Comment: @ redneb Thanks I will check it out. Btw, is there any comprehensive tutorial to understand the ins and outs of the C FFI? Most tutorials on the web seem really scratchy and low on examples and even the ones which are present seem a bit ad hoc.

Comment: There's also `Data.Array.Storable`.